# Multiply each element of a column by each element of a different dataframe

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have two data frame both having same number of columns but the first data frame has multiple rows and the second one has only one row but same number of columns as the first one. I need to multiply the entries of the first data frame with the second by column name.

DF:1
  A   B   C
0  34  54  56
1  12  87  78
2  78  35   0
3  84  25  14
4  26  82  13

DF:2

A  B  C
0  2  3  1

Result
A     B    C
68   162  56
24   261  78
156  105   0
168   75  14
52   246  13

Comment: Have you tried just `first * second` or maybe `first.mul(second, axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes that gives null values for rest of the rows apart from the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. Here we are manipulating numpy array inside the DataFrame.

`pd.DataFrame(df1.values*df2.values, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)`

Comment: Great..thanks @shashank sherkhar this was swift and easy

Answer (score 0):

```py
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: x * df2[col])
```

theres probably an even simpler solution. Play around with apply, map and transform

Comment: This works that you so much.One more way i figured out is to convert the the entire elements in the row to a list and then do a multiplication as suggested by Jon Clements in the comment above